# Throw Exception - NoSuchElementException when exiting remote desktop connection (IEDriver)

Tags: internet-explorer, selenium, nosuchelementexception

I am Executing my selenium automation script on IE driver in remote machine through mstsc(Remote desktop). It throws no such element exception. this happens only when I have started the execution and logged out from the remote machine or if the remote desktop window is minimized.
However automation script works fine when I keep the remote window open
would like to know if there is anything I am doing wrong

Comment: strange it should work, the RDC on virtual environment of physical station?

Comment: It is just an physical machine with Windows 8.1 OS

Comment: You tried to use phantomjs driver?

Comment: Nope, I tried with fire fox. it works fine